# Python pyinstaller pydocx

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-docx

I have a python application that makes use of some libraries including python-docx. Inside the application I have a templates/*.docx directory that contains some docx files with empty tables that I copy and fill in the app logic. And this works fine when I run the program from the command line.

However when I use pyinstaller --onefile --add-data templates/*docx;. main.py (I'm on windows) then then pyinstaller creates an exe, but when executing that exe I get an error in the command line: **Error: Package not found at 'medium_risk.docx'**. Note this in a try/catch block where I print the exception. Tried a lot of different things but just can't get it to work.

Anyone has an idea? That would be great.

Comment: Check https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file

Comment: I have and updated my script to use that. Now I get: **Package not found at 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI<number>\templates\medium_risk.docx'**.